# D Latches & D Flip Flops

Tags: digital-logic, latch

I am trying to recreate this D-Latch using only logic gates:

[image: D-Latch]

So far I have this for the latch:

[image: Latch circuit]

What am I missing here?  There should only be one input of c and an output of A1, so I tried connecting the inverter directly to the output of A1 since there is no input of D allowed.  But something is still wrong, because the D input isn't connected directly to the output in that picture but how can I show this using only logic gates and not directly having D as input?? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at: [Wikipdia: D-Latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Gated_D_latch)

Specifically, this figure:

[image]

The inverting buffer is already required from the D input, and inverting Q to the input of D is a double negative.

Note that the lower And gate has a non-inverted input form D, so you could just move the not gate from the top and gate to the bottom.

The "un-optimized solution":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8B8wF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using the double not-gate optimization:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0ftI.png)</sup>

"Cheating" and getting rid of both not gates:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLMLxt.png)</sup>

Comment: If I take out the NOT gate what goes on the input of the AND gate?  Do I attach that to A1?

Comment: I updated with actual schematics showing the basic solution and two possible optimized equivalents.

Comment: Thank you!  Since I am only suppose to have an output of A1, I can ignore using !A1 as another output and just leave it blank correct?

Comment: Yep, it's perfectly fine to leave it unconnected as an output.

Comment: Thank you so the final circuit you designed should be equivalent to the one in my original post.  I appreciate it!

Comment: At a purely logical level, yes it should be equivalent to your original circuit. Dunno how well this behaves in practice with real components, particularly around corner cases.